# How to use parametrs if in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium IDE and I got errors from site:

```
The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrador.

Your support ID is: < 9090328340196296747>

[Go Back]
```

My question is, how to create ruls in Selenium IDE, if I get this error, then the task must start from the beginning? Number always random.